# How can I remap the Caps Lock key in Mac OS X Mavericks?

Tags: keyboard, capslock

What's the easiest way to map the Control key to Caps Lock? I just want to make it easier when I'm programming

Comment: [Switch the keys caps lock and shift](https://superuser.com/q/154707/)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned an the answer to [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/310008/how-can-i-remap-the-caps-lock-key-in-mac-os-x-lion) for OS X Lion, many people use [PCKeyboardHack](https://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/pckeyboardhack.html.en) to remap caps lock.

This works for me on an upgraded Mavericks install.

See [this github issue](https://github.com/tekezo/PCKeyboardHack/issues/22) for a discussion on Mavericks compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

`Mavericks` gives you a few options built-in via `System Preferences`:

1. Open `System Preferences`
2. Open `Keyboard` preferences
3. On the `Keyboard` tab, click the `Modifier Keys...` button
4. See `Caps Lock Key` options
5. Current options are `Caps Lock`, `Control`, `Option`, `Command` and `No Action`